# Combinatorics question - How many different ways to change sitting order

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, necklace-and-bracelets

Six children ($a$ through $f$) are playing on a carousel with 6 seats such that $a$ is sitting in front of $d$, $b$ is sitting in front of $e$, and $c$ is sitting in front of $f$.

How many ways are there to change the sitting order, such that no child is sitting in front of the child they are sitting in front of now?

So for example, if child $a$ is sitting in seat number $1$, child $b$ is sitting in $2$ and so on, how many combinations are there such that $a$ is not in front of $d$, $b$ is not in front of $e$ and $c$ is not in front of $f$.

Comment: If we take kid $a$ as a starting point, there are $5! = 120$ possible permutations. $2$ of those satisfy your description of the initial state: $(a,d,b,e,c,f)$ and $(a,d,c,f,b,e)$.

Comment: In other words, either $f$ or $e$ is sitting in front of $a$, either $d$ or $f$ in front of $b$, and either $d$ or $e$ in front of $c$. Do these count as well towards the pairings you want to eliminate from your resulting sitting order, or do these not matter? And just to be clear, we're talking about a carousel like [thise one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:2010-09-30._Cabali%C3%B1os_en_Portos%C3%ADn._Porto_do_Son._Galiza.jpg), but with 6 seats / horses instead of 4, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a case of counting possibilities.  $a$ can go in $6$ seats.  $d$ then has four choices, but you need to distinguish whether the remaining seats are in a group of $4$, groups of $1,3$ or groups of $2,2$.  For each one, see how many ways there are to position $b,e$. Have you tried?

Comment: Actually, since it's a carousel, kid $a$ should go in seat $1$; all other solutions are rotations of that solution.

Comment: @ATS:  you can do it either way, you just need to specify what you are doing.  As OP named the seats, I assumed that rotations are considered distinct.